# micropython warnings: "initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type"

Tags: micropython

I am working on a C module for micropython. It compiles fine, but I get a lot of warnings and I would like to know what I am doing wrong. I have tried to work according to [this tutorial](https://micropython-usermod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usermods_05.html). But I am getting warnings when I compile.

- Is there any way to get rid of the warnings?
- What am I doing wrong?

**Here are the warnings**

```
./../subprojects/micropython/py/obj.h:309:23: warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
    309 | #define MP_ROM_PTR(p) (p)
        |                       ^
  ../test.c:9:38: note: in expansion of macro 'MP_ROM_PTR'
      9 |     { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_test),     MP_ROM_PTR(&test_obj) },
```

The project is quite extensive at this time, but here is a simplified version of the files causing the warnings. As I have understood it this warning means that I cannot change what I am pointing to, but I am not sure about it. As I followed a tutorial and have followed it step by step except splitting the file from just .c into three different files. Not sure if it matters but I am running a SAME54 XPLAINED.

**test.c:**

```
#include "test.h"
STATIC MP_DEFINE_CONST_FUN_OBJ_1(test_obj, Test_testfunction);

STATIC const mp_map_elem_t Test_globals_table[] = {
    // module name
    { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR___name__), MP_OBJ_NEW_QSTR(MP_QSTR_Test) },
    // function names
    { MP_ROM_QSTR(MP_QSTR_test),     MP_ROM_PTR(&test_obj) },
};

STATIC MP_DEFINE_CONST_DICT (mp_module_Test_globals, Test_globals_table);

const mp_obj_module_t Test_cmodule = {  
    .base = { &mp_type_module },
    .globals = (mp_obj_dict_t*)&mp_module_Test_globals,
};

MP_REGISTER_MODULE(MP_QSTR_Test, Test_cmodule, 1);
```

**test.h:**

```
#ifndef _TEST_H_
#define _TEST_H_

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "py/obj.h"

mp_obj_t Test_testfunction(mp_obj_t o_in);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif // _TEST_H_
```

**testimpl.cpp:**

```
#include "test.h"
#ifndef NO_QSTR
#endif
 
extern "C" {
#include "py/builtin.h"
#include "py/objlist.h"
#include "py/runtime.h"
}

mp_obj_t Test_testfunction(mp_obj_t o_in) {
    int i = mp_obj_get_int(o_in);
    return mp_obj_new_int(i);
}
```

Comment: This got rid of the warnings, but since I am new at micropython/c /c++ I am not sure what effects this causes: `(const mp_obj_t)`